# How to make one part symmetrical on all sides?

Tags: objects

I don't get how to make highlited part 0 in parts 2 and 3 (1 is symmetry by -x and x). It should have the same distance between each other(perpendicularly).

I have attached the file itself.
[image]

[image]

Comment: That's because the 3D cursor isn't in the centre of the circle. The symetry happens across the 3D cursor so you need to put that in the centre. I'd suggest you Alt-click one of the rings of vertices to select the ring then use Shift-S > Cursor to Selected to centre the cursor then try again. If that doesn't have the desired effect you'll need to share your blend file so that someone here can have a look at it.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: @JohnEason I have uploaded a file by your request. I also have centered the 3d cursor on the circle, but I still can't make parts 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mirror 0 on 1 with the *Mirror* modifier, enable the X axis on *Axis*, *Bisect* and *Flip*:

[image]

To do 2 and 3 you could move your mesh so that the origin is between the 2 holes, select the piece of the mesh that you want to symmetrize and *Mesh > Symmetrize*, choose -Y to +Y in the *Operator Box*, then you'll need to join the piece to the cylinder with a bit of topology work:

[image]

Comment: [https://ibb.co/4RKnSB6] Here's what happens if I symmetrize.  I am just a beginner and maybe this is topology problem you are talking about? However, the symmetrized piece is too unaligned.

Comment: I can't see the picture, but actually maybe you should redo the object from scratch with a clean topology?

Comment: It is already made .stl file and I have to modify it, if it helps I can also add an .stl file. (copy the link with brackets (just delete them after) and paste it in the search)

Comment: The problem in your image is that the origin is not correctly placed, move the whole mesh so that it is placed between the 2 inner holes, because the symmetry will use the origin as center

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about the origin. Now it worked and I have to connect it.